# How can I copy several directories with expect?

Tags: bash

I have the following script which I adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346509/automate-scp-file-transfer-using-a-shell-script. The script works very well for copying one directory. I have several directories which I want to copy, each named according to the day of the month.
Can someone help me how to loop, copying each directory, if possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
spawn scp -r "zmd1@ranger.zamren.zm:/data/scratch/ZMWRF/ZMD/WRF/OUTPUT/2020061100" ./

#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
 }
 -re ".*sword.*" {
 exp_send "PASSWORD\r"
}
}

interact
```

Comment: In what method do you want these to be copied/? You can just add wildcards instead of the fixed date you have in there to copy everything that matches. You can also change it to current date or part of a date and have it copy today or this month or this year.

Comment: Since `expect` uses `tcl`, you should be able to use a `foreach` loop. See for example [wiki.tcl-lang.org](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/foreach)

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind, wildcard sounds a workable solution which I never thought about. I will try it when I will have access to my remote server and confirm if it works or not. I looked at  wiki.tcl-lang.org but cannot figure out how to use it. I think the wild card looks pure and simple.

Comment: I can now confirm that the expect script works perfectly with wild card directory. Thnaks once more @Rinzwind